# Extract file descriptors from fds_bits

Tags: c, linux, debugging, posix, file-descriptor

I am debugging timing-dependent bug (mthe bug appears after months of execution, as far as I know). I suspect that the problem is a call to `pselect()` with a set of file descriptors which contains only "bad/broken" ones.

### What I want to do

In order to reproduce the error, I want to run the program and delete the file descriptors it is using (apart from 0, 1 and 2). To achieve this, I want to go to `/proc/<pid>/fd` and unlink file descrpitors while the program is running.

### The problem

When I debug the program with gdb, the set of file descriptors given to `pselect()` appears as following:

```
{fds_bits = {16384, 8, 0 <repeats 30 times>}}
```

Is there any way to obtain the file descriptors from the `fds_bits`? Is there any other way to achieve what I want to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What the macros `FD_ISSET(nr, set)` etc. do is basically to interpret the array fds_bits as a large bitfield. Bit n represents filedescriptor n.

So in the first array member `16384` (binary 100000000000000) bit nr 14 is set, which represents filedescriptor 14.

In the second array-member `8` (binary 1000) is set, which is the 4th bit. The array members are of type `unsigned long int`, so on a 64-bit-machine, the least significant bit of fdbits[1] represents filedescriptor 64 and the set bit therefore stands for filedescriptor 68. On a 32-bit machine this would be fd 36 (32 + 4).

Together, the fd-set you are inspecting therefore represents the two filedescriptors 14 and 68.